# After Effects Expression to get 3rd point in a triangle with 2 points & all lengths known (but variable)

Tags: javascript, math, expression, algebra, after-effects

Caveat A: This is a personal project solely for the purpose of learning, so I don't need a better way to skin this cat.

Caveat B: I have looked at [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543961/determine-third-point-of-triangle-when-two-points-and-all-sides-are-known) for a while & it doesn't quite get me where I need to go because it assumes that the B is on the same y coordinate as A. I don't have that luxury.

I am trying to build out a sort of IK chain for a character in After Effects with expressions. For the legs(also the arms for that matter, but one step at a time), I was thinking I could use the formula to determine the point in a triangle (hip to knee to foot, 3 points, a triangle) but I have never been good at math & the last math class I took was 15 years ago.

I have the calf parented to the hip, & the foot parented to the calf. So the anchor point of the hip is essentially the origin. I know in the code below there will be a little bit of `toWorld` or `toComp` trickery but I wanted to get the actual equation down first.

[Reference Image A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HRfV.png)
[Reference Image B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPFc2.png)

Down below you can see the code I have so far to see the variables I am referencing. With that in mind here are the two equations I *think* I am supposed to use.

```
Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) = Math.pow(A2B, 2)
Math.pow((x - C.position[0]), 2) + Math.pow((y - C.position[1]), 2) = Math.pow(A2B, 2)
```

or in more traditional syntax

- xˆ2 + yˆ2 = A2Bˆ2
- (x - Cx)ˆ2 + (y - Cy)ˆ2 = B2Cˆ2

If I am solving the first equation for y I get this. `y = A2B - x`

*showing my work*

- xˆ2 + yˆ2 = A2Bˆ2
- yˆ2 = A2Bˆ2 - xˆ2
- y = √(A2Bˆ2 - xˆ2)
- y = A2B - x

  *I am not even sure if this is correct....*

That being said here's what I have worked up so far.

```
// A is the hip
A = thisComp.layer("HIP");
// B is the calf
B = thisLayer;
// C is the foot
C = thisComp.layer("FOOT");
// A2B & B2C are both fixed lengths, based on the size of the layer.
A2B = A.height - (B.anchorPoint[1] * 2);
B2C = B.height - (C.anchorPoint[1] * 2);
A2C = length(A.position, C.position);

y = A2B - x;
```

This where I get stuck. I plug y into the second equation & it gets wooly really fast.

```
Math.pow(((A2B - x) - C.position[0]), 2) + Math.pow(((A2B - x) - C.position[1]), 2) = Math.pow(B2C, 2)
```

or

- ((A2B - x) - Cx)ˆ2 + ((A2B - x) - Cy)ˆ2 = B2Cˆ2

Trying to solve this for x so I can plug that back into y is eluding me. X is used twice here & it's buried within a parenthetical & part of an exponent. I can't wrap my head around how to pull X out of the bear traps that its in.

Also if it's easier to write the answer out in traditional math syntax I can read that (mostly) too.

Lastly, like I said above I haven't taken a math class in over a decade so if my terminology is wrong or this is super easy (if you must laugh at me, do it privately... please) or anything along those lines, I apologize in advance.

Help me Obi-Wans, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 0):

```
x^2 + y^2 = a^2    (1)
(x-cx)^2 + (y-cy)^2 = c^2  
so
x^2 - 2*x*cx + cx^2 + y^2 - 2*y*cy + cy^2 = c^2   (2)
subtract (2) from (1)
2*x*cx - cx^2 + 2*y*cy - cy^2 = a^2 - c^2
y = (a^2 - c^2 - 2*x*cx + cx^2 + cy^2) / (2*cy)     (3)
```

substitute `y` from (3) into (1) and solve quadratic equation for `x` - you'll get two (if possible) coordinates